# Fancyhdr vertical overlap with body section title

Tags: fancyhdr, mactex

I am writing up a product report, and building my header with fancyhdr.

On the first page, the section header (in the body) is overlapping with the page header, as shown here:

[image: Overlapping header and text body]

This is not repeated on following pages:

[image: Non-overlapping body text]

The header is specified as a 2-line table in the left side, and a 3-line table in the right side.

How can I remove the overlap with the section title? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
```

to see the margins configuration. Then you can set it up and increase the distance between the text area and the header (namely `headsep`). For example,

```
\usepackage[showframe,headsep=1cm,headheight=2cm]{geometry}.
```

Comment: This ruins the horizontal centering of the body.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I have solved by equaling headheight to the font size (mine was 14 pt) i.e.

`\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}`

I hope that this help.